# Invalid query: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, insert-into

I have a strange problem, I'm sending an SQL query through PHP:

```
INSERT INTO `lib_plex` (`id`, `active`, `lastUpdated`, `entry_date`, `entry_ip`, `address`, `city`, `state_iso`, `zip_code`, `plex_type`, `price`, `has_garage`, `has_indoor_parking`, `has_outdoor_parking`, `has_pool`, `has_fireplace`, `average_nb_room`, `construction_year`, `building_material`) 

VALUES ('','1','2010-10-27 13:22:59','2010-10-27 13:22:59','2130706433','COMMERCE ST.','85825','OK','73521','commercial','595000','0','0','0','0','0','11','','Aluminum Siding')
```

And it throws me this error:
**Invalid query: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**.
Although, when I paste and run the same exact query in PhpMyAdmin, it works perfectly, so it got me quite confused...

I counted the number of columns and the the number of values, and they match (19). I tried to remove the 'id' field, since it's auto-incremented, but it didn't change anything. What am I doing wrong? And why does it work in PhpMyAdmin?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

here's the php code:

```
$values = array('', 1, $lastUpdated, $entry_date, $entry_ip, $streetName, $cityId, $listing['stateorprovince'], $listing['postalcode'], $listing['type'], $listing['listprice'], $has_garage, $has_indoor_parking, $has_outdoor_parking, $has_pool, $has_fireplace, $average_nb_room, $listing['yearbuilt'], $listing['exteriortype']); 

$q = "INSERT INTO `lib_plex` (`id`, `active`, `lastUpdated`, `entry_date`, `entry_ip`, `address`, `city`, `state_iso`, `zip_code`, `plex_type`, `price`, `has_garage`, `has_indoor_parking`, `has_outdoor_parking`, `has_pool`, `has_fireplace`, `average_nb_room`, `construction_year`, `building_material`) 
VALUES ('".htmlentities(implode("','",$values),ENT_QUOTES)."')";

$this->execMysqlQuery($q);
```

and the method that is being called:

```
private function execMysqlQuery($q, $returnResults = false, $returnInsertId = false){
$c = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_LOGIN,DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $c);

$result = mysql_query($q);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error(). "<br/>=>".$q);
}

if ($returnInsertId)
    return mysql_insert_id();

mysql_close($c);

if ($returnResults)
    return $result;

return true;
}
```

And the error:

```
Invalid query: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
=>INSERT INTO `lib_plex` (`id`, `active`, `lastUpdated`, `entry_date`, `entry_ip`, `address`, `city`, `state_iso`, `zip_code`, `plex_type`, `price`, `has_garage`, `has_indoor_parking`, `has_outdoor_parking`, `has_pool`, `has_fireplace`, `average_nb_room`, `construction_year`, `building_material`) VALUES ('','1','2010-10-27 13:47:35','2010-10-27 13:47:35','2130706433','COMMERCE ST.','85825','OK','73521','commercial','595000','0','0','0','0','0','11','','Aluminum Siding')
```

Comment: Can you show us the PHP code where this query is assigned?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you've selected the right database in your code?

Comment: thanks for your questions, I included the code in my last edit

Comment: Yes I am certain that I have selected the good database, as it is defined by a constant in a config file and I only work with one database

Comment: Can you run the command in the mysql client?  Also, could you post the table CREATE statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print `$q`, I'm willing to bet it'll look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `lib_plex` (`id`, `active`, `lastUpdated`, `entry_date`, `entry_ip`, `address`, `city`, `state_iso`, `zip_code`, `plex_type`, `price`, `has_garage`, `has_indoor_parking`, `has_outdoor_parking`, `has_pool`, `has_fireplace`, `average_nb_room`, `construction_year`, `building_material`) 
VALUES ('&#39;,&#39;1&#39;,&#39;2010-10-27 13:22:59&#39;,&#39;2010-10-27 13:22:59&#39;,&#39;2130706433&#39;,&#39;COMMERCE ST.&#39;,&#39;85825&#39;,&#39;OK&#39;,&#39;73521&#39;,&#39;commercial&#39;,&#39;595000&#39;,&#39;0&#39;,&#39;0&#39;,&#39;0&#39;,&#39;0&#39;,&#39;0&#39;,&#39;11&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;Aluminum Siding');
```

(I don't have PHP at work; this is a guess)

In other words, `htmlentities` is turning your quotes into HTML Entities.  Specifically, turning `'` to `&#39;`

Don't use `htmlentities` on things that aren't being sent to the web browser.  Use your database driver's escaping method ([`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)) on each individual value being sent in.

Edit: Better yet, use prepared statements and data binding with [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), which will automatically escape the data as you bind it.

Comment: Oh my god, thanks for making me feel like an idiot :] that was it!

Comment: I would use MySQLi or PDO, but I'm working for a client and I'm not sure if I'm permitted to use PDO or MySQLi on their server. I'm forced to work in a custom php framework (not mine) that uses its own query methods, which are usually effective enough. It's just that in this case, I have to insert a big amount of entries and those methods seem to cause some memory leak when used massively... So I have to resort to basic mysql

again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ($insert) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO employee VALUES ($empno,'$lname','$fname','$init','$gender','$bdate','$dept','$position',$pay,$dayswork,$otrate,$othrs,$allow,$advances,$insurance,'')";
    $msg = "New record saved!";
  }
  else {
    $query = "UPDATE employee SET empno=$empno,lname='$lname',fname='$fname',init= '$init',gender='$gender',bdate='$bdate',dept='$dept',position='$position',pay=$pay,dayswork=$dayswork,otrate=$otrate,othrs=$othrs,allow=$allow,advances=$advances,insurance=$insurance WHERE empno = $empno";
    $msg = "Record updated!";
  }
  include 'include/dbconnection.php';
  $result=mysql_query ($query,$link) or die ("invalid query".mysql_error());
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)